# Avoiding SIGPIPE in mac osx - reg

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, signals

In order to avoid SIGPIPE in mac osx 
i tried using the flag

```
 SO_NOSIGPIPE
```

which is equivalent of

```
 MSG_NOSIGNAL
```

in linux. But still SIGPIPE error is coming. How to avoid it ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does ignoring `SIGPIPE` work?

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: Actually i was just writing a simple server. While sending response back my execution was stopping once SIGPIPE was coming. So, that is why i wanted to avoid it. I mean the execution shouldn't cease even when SIGPIPE comes. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Chaitanya No, you want to close the connection and carry on.  `read()` will fail and you can check `errno` to ensure it's an error relating to the other end dropping out and then closedown that client connection.  You can do this while ignoring `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: For me `read()` was going on properly. It was receiving nothing in the read buffer. It was of zero length. For me problem was coming while sending response to client again. There execution was stopping. So I need to handle those errors ?

Comment: You should probably use `poll()` to see when data is ready for reading/writing and to test for error/hang-ups.

Comment: i mean that is what `accept()` does right. It accepts only when there is an incoming  connection and then reads. But for me the case is like sometimes 0 length string is being read. Of course the problem was getting solved, if read string is `>0` only. But i felt like that was not correct procedure.

Comment: I thought your question was "how to avoid SIGPIPE", but it seems you really want to know how to read/write data via a socket?  Perhaps you should edit your question to reflect what you really want to know.

Comment: Oh! Ok. I wil get back in another post. Thanks. :)